# C# unable to convert complex json write to csv

Tags: c#, json.net, export-to-csv

I am new to converting json to csv. I have a complex json file. I am trying with following code to strongly derserialize to c# class. but nothing is working.  firstly not able to deserialize and not sure the best way to write this to csv. there are around 20 entries in the json like "0", ..."19".

json data:

```
{
  "0": [
    {
      "filenames": [
        "a.txt",
        "b.txt",
        "c.txt"
      ]
    },
    {
      "cluster_number": 0
    },
    {
      "Top_Terms": [
        "would",
        "get",
        "like"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "filenames": [
        "a.txt",
        "b.txt",
        "c.txt"
      ]
    },
    {
      "cluster_number": 0
    },
    {
      "Top_Terms": [
        "would",
        "get",
        "like"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

c# classes:

```
[DataContract(Name ="0")]
public class Zero
{
    public IList<string> filenames { get; set; }
    public int? cluster_number { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Top_Terms { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "1")]
public class One
{
    public IList<string> filenames { get; set; }
    public int? cluster_number { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Top_Terms { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Example
{
    public IList<Zero> Zero { get; set; }
    public IList<One> One { get; set; }
}

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("data.json"))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json);

        }
```

Comment: csv doesn't do any justice to json, how can you convert it securely? Your json could be serialized of a `Dictionary<string, object>` (you could theoretically write the object in a stronger way like using your `Zero` class) or you could just use `JObject`. There is no need to make 20 classes, as when your json changes, you would have to do another change in your classes (which you don't want, you want your solution to be somewhat generic I guess). How do you expect the final outcome of your CSV file?

Comment: Try [Quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs) to generate C# classes from your json and then parse it from there. You'll see it produces different types than what you have here, the main reason being that you have an **array containing three different data structures as siblings of each other**.

Comment: I am looking the csv in this format filename (without .txt) | cluster_number | top_terms

Comment: @Icepickle how this can be done in a generic way pls?

Comment: csv doesn't support layer like your classes.  Better to serialize to xml instead of csv.

Comment: @MukilDeepthi maybe consider a custom deserializer for your one custom C# class? I'd be good to know what would be the outcome csv

Comment: If you really want csv start by opening a blank excel workbook and put data into a worksheet.  Then write code to save the data in the same columns that you used in the excel worksheet.